# creating new lists by adding elements of lists

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following two lists:

```
a = ['hello ', 'goodbye ']
b = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
```

I would like to create two new lists with out put as follows:

```
['hello tom', 'hello dick', 'hello harry']
['goodbye tom', 'goodbye dick', 'goodbye harry']
```

what would be the most pythonic way to do this? my guess is there is something more elegant and efficient than a nested loop, but given that a or b could be different sizes, does this require a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could produce those in a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
[['{} {}'.format(greeting, name) for name in b] for greeting in a]
```

That produces a *list of lists*:

```
>>> a = ['hello ', 'goodbye ']
>>> b = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
>>> [['{} {}'.format(greeting, name) for name in b] for greeting in a]
[['hello  tom', 'hello  dick', 'hello  harry'], ['goodbye  tom', 'goodbye  dick', 'goodbye  harry']]
```

Comment: is the formatting part of this required? i'm a little confused by the greeting and name part of your answer - are those specific keywords in python? i'm looking to keep this fairly general, as the problem in question may not always be of this variety

Comment: @laszlopanaflex: The `str.format()` produces the `'greeting name'` pattern of strings. `name` and `greeting` are just variable names.

Comment: @laszlopanaflex: I've added a link to the relevant section of the Python tutorial for you; you may want to read the wider context of that section too.

Comment: thanks a lot. is there just a better way to understand the order of operations here - i.e., you have "(greeting,name) for name in b" before "for greeting in a". clearly, the order/pattern affects the output but the intuition is not clear to me, even after reading the link you added...

Comment: @laszlopanaflex: the pattern is `[expression for target in iterable]`. The `for target in iterable` part forms a loop, and for each iteration `expression` is executed to produce the next element in the list.

Comment: @laszlopanaflex: in this case, `expression` is *another* list comprehension. So for each iteration in the outer list comprehension, a new list comprehension is run.